1990s sci-fi/horror film or episode where device lets women look into an underwater parallel dimension
I believe this was from 1990s because I recall the images being sleek, like the re-make of Outer Limits. Not grainy. Not cheap film. Not foreign either (like Italy); they spoke English. Pretty sure this was on a cable channel too. The production was slick, but there was also a cheesy feel to it.
Here is what I recall: 
Two women, one of them in uniform (brunette?) and more sophisticated, the other more relaxed like normal fashion clothes (blonde? skirt?). Both very attractive and in their 20s. We're in the future from the look of the nearly spaceship sleek room (although I don't know that we're actually in space).
The woman in the uniform/pantsuit is explaining about a device that another scientist is working on, perhaps she works for this scientist. I believe the device was like a small arc or perhaps like Star Trek's transporting device, but the idea was that it disturbed/altered the space around it and one did not have to necessarily walk through a gateway or anything. Purple glow was a part of how its effects took place.
The other woman talks her into turning on the device (although it hasn't been working?) and we start to see purple glowing things that eventually look like fish -- strange-looking prehistoric fish that are translucent, one's hand goes right through them like ghosts.
The darker-haired woman explains how dimensions work, that they are on top of each other, so this is all happening at the same time, one doesn't have to walk into another dimension because it is already there and this device allows that to be revealed. She believes the dimension we're looking at to be perhaps like primitive Earth and therefore it is under the ocean. 
At a point we see a human-like form, in what appears to be an astronaut uniform type deal (if I recall that correctly) and inside the helmet is a face that looks part fish and part human; sentient, but transparent too like the regular-sized fish. This understandably distracts and amazes them, although the being doesn't say anything or act violently, nor can we see it completely clearly or in full color.
At the same time, one of the fish with the razor sharp teeth seems to get more life-like, less transparent and goes for the face of one of the women. 
This causes them to unplug/turn off the device.
Something is said about the fear/possibility that the beings could've perhaps crossed into our world (since the inhabitants should not have seen us?). And I think the darker-haired woman is excited that the device worked so well. 

I've tracked down so many obscure things in my life that I enjoyed, but I never did get to see the end of whatever this was (late night on a school night). I hope that I remembered things accurately enough. I usually do. Anyway, I'm really stumped and have searched regularly without luck of the right key words...
It is not "From Beyond", "Xtro", "TerrorVision", or any "Piranha" film despite the alien fish's similarity to them.

Geez, can we have some details, though?? [Just kidding... :) A very nice question, +1. The part with the fish guy in an astronaut suit sounds really familiar, but maybe I'm just mixing it up with certain aspects of A Sound of Thunder.]

I simply have no clue. The image of the transparent fish is making me think of the movie Sphere and/or Abyss but I'm pretty sure its neither of those.

@sanpaco Yeah, if it wasn't answered yet, I'm guessing it's much more obscure than those films (or an old TV episode, which are harder to remember). I thought about Ferocious Planet, but it's not that either.

Outer Limits like from 1990s... Tales from the Darkside?

As another possible long shot, The Hunger was a series that I believe had a few sci fi episodes.

stumped :( almost has to be a tv-movie or wrong decade entirely. This place is like nineties-central ;)

I thought I'd found a possible candidate - a film where a blonde female professional is shown an inter-dimensional transport machine to a primitive world. It turns out I was very wrong, but I'll link this review here anyway, because it's funny: Prisoners of the Lost Universe

Fish head things didn't look like this, did they? http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Nakai I assume you've ruled out Stargate and its 10,000 spin-offs?

@xxmightyonexx  could be Xtro II: The Second Encounter.   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OXI4Vp_qpyI

The core? Or sphere I think?? Try it:)

Creature? Could be?

Almost sounds like the premise of a porn movie >_<

I really want to see this now

Could it be SG-1 Season 6 episode 13 (Sight Unseen)? It has some similiarities with some of your details but not all of them, so I don't know if this is it.

SG-1 comes back to Stargate Command with a strange device which was built by the Ancients. While they talk about the device, Jonas Quinn suddenly sees a large, flying, insect-like being, which seems to fly through the wall. However, no one else witnessed the being. Nevertheless, Major General George S. Hammond orders the lockdown of the base. The searches turn up nothing, so Jonas' comrades think he might be having hallucinations.
While Colonel Jack O'Neill leaves the base to go fishing, Major Samantha Carter and Jonas examine the device. During their research, Jonas again sees a large insect and is immediately examined by Dr. Janet Fraiser. Nothing unusual is found in the scans, but nevertheless, Hammond removes Jonas from active duty


Sounds a lot like "From Beyond", an adaptation of a short story of the same name by H. P. Lovecraft.
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091083/
A group of scientists have developed the Resonator, a machine which allows whoever is within range to see beyond normal perceptible reality. But when the experiment succeeds, they are immediately attacked by terrible life forms. 

I do believe you are referring to an episode of Star Trek: The Next Generation.
Realm of Fear. Season 6 episode 2
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0708761/?ref_=ttep_ep2

Literally nothing in that episode matches with anything described in the question.
